# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nan' when trying to replace 0 in NaN

Tags: python, numpy, null

I have  nd-array with 7 dimensions. I want to change in each band the 0 value into None value (nan).

I have tried to this it like this:

```
band[band == 0] = "nan"
```

but then I got the error message:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nan'

I have tried to change the nan to None and also np.nan but for the none I have got following error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
> number, not 'NoneType'

and for np.nan:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

The array values type is numpy.int64 .

My endgoal here is to be able to change the 0 values into nan values for the array.

Comment: You cannot store `NaN` in an array of integers, because it is not an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your array data type to `float`. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,1,2,3],dtype=float)
a[a==0] = np.nan
```